# How to mathematically calculate individual pixel values after each image rotation?

Tags: python, opencv, interpolation

If I have an image that is being rotated using OpenCV in python, about its centre, How do I mathematically calculate the pixel values after each rotation?

A python code for this operation would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: a bit off topic in my opinion. If the rotation is by angle of 90° I would start with np.rot90.

Comment: Yes, but I am rotating the image in increments of 0.01 degrees. How do I mathematically calculate the pixel values without actually rotating the image and checking it each time?

Comment: seems like to have to do some basic trigonometry ...